# python Input delegation for subprocesses

Tags: shell, python-3.x, subprocess, python-idle

I am currently displaying the output of a subprocess onthe python shell (in my case iDLE on windows) by using a pipe and displaying each line.

I want to do this with a subprocess that has user input, so that the prompt will appear on the python console, and the user can enter the result, and the result can be send to the subprocess.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `process.stdin.write`.

Remember to set `stdin = subprocess.PIPE` when you call `subprocess.Popen`.